# Trying to install numpy in setup.py

Tags: python, numpy

I know this is a heavily documented issue, but none of the posted solutions have fixed my issue.

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext as _build_ext

class build_ext(_build_ext):
    def finalize_options(self):
    _build_ext.finalize_options(self)
    # Prevent numpy from thinking it is still in its setup process:
    __builtins__.__NUMPY_SETUP__ = False
    import numpy
    self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

setup(
  name='MLM',
  version='0.2dev',
  setup_requires=['numpy'],
  cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
  install_requires=[
    'nltk', 
    'numpy'
  ],
  license='MIT',
  long_description=open('../README.md').read,
```

)

However, when I run `python setup.py install` I get:

```
File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 1106, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
```

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions and installed MSVC++ 9?

Comment: @lxop Is that something that could be added to the setup.py file?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you received is pretty clear:

> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27

I think that you haven't tried that because I suspect that if you did it either would have worked for you, or more likely you would be asking a different question.

However, following the steps provided in the error message is likely not the best choice in this one specific case.  Instead, I would recommend downloading and installing a pre-compiled version of numpy for windows, perhaps the officially provided version here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/install.html#windows

In this case, I suspect the pre-compiled version is a better choice than trying to build your own because numpy doesn't just require the appropriate C++ compiler for windows, it will then also require a compatible FORTRAN-77 compiler, and then a bunch of additional libraries, which in turn may have their own requirements.